# Android studio login system

Tags: android

i am trying to create a login system on android studio using java, i have tried a piece of code i have found and modifies it to my own program- i am getting errors that the tutorial cannot explain and would appreciate if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong. 
on line  10 under username it says expression expected 
The else statement says there should be an if but as you can see there is ?

```
    public void LoginButton(){
        UserName = findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        userPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        userPin = findViewById(R.id.userPin);
        GoBtn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (UserName.getText().toString().equals("user");// here i would preferably link to a database but do to time restaitns i have modeled it with user
                        userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass");
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and password is correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Username and password is NOT correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


    }
```

I need this to lead the user to the next activty if the input is correct but so far i cannot get it to run due to the errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Issues**

1. You can't use a semicolon (`;`) right after if statement because an empty `;` is also considered a statement.
2. If Statement is incorrect: It has to be a valid statement
3. Many braces (`{` and `}`) are missing

Here is a **sample** code

```
public void LoginButton() {
    UserName = findViewById(R.id.UserName);
    userPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
    userPin = findViewById(R.id.userPin);
    GoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (UserName.getText().toString().equals("user") &&
                    userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                // use your code
            } else {
                // use your code 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Suggestion:** Please read more Java

Answer (score 0):

your if condition syntax is wrong you need to use AND operator(&&).

change these lines

```
if (UserName.getText().toString().equals("user");
userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass");
```

to

```
if((UserName.getText().toString().equals("user")) && (userPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass")))
```